# Centos 6.2 cant ping 8.8.8.8 using NAT bridge on VMWare

Tags: networking, vmware-player, centos-6

I am using Centos 6.2 inside vmware and I have three nodes whihc I have assigned them static IPs as folllow

Based on the errors, you need to update the files to look like this:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR=00:0C:29:04:B4:3C
IPADDR=192.168.24.129
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eth0"
UUID="17eeb7fe-f11c-4b8b-83be-a9dd2281dda2"
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

`/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=centos7
GATEWAY=192.168.24.129
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

`ifconfig` output is as follows:

```
[root@master ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:04:B4:3C
          inet addr:192.168.24.129  Bcast:192.168.24.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe04:b43c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10384 (10.1 KiB)  TX bytes:11652 (11.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2300 (2.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2300 (2.2 KiB)
```

I am using NAT on my vmware and have enabled ip4 package forwarding (Switchning to Bridged network I even cant ping to other nodes in the network!)

```
# vi /etc/sysctl.conf 
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I can ping other nodes in the network but not `8.8.8.8`, it stucks for a long time:

```
[root@master ~]# ping 192.168.24.130
PING 192.168.24.130 (192.168.24.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.24.130: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.423 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.24.130: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.701 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.24.130: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.09 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.24.130: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.24.130: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.761 ms
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ping 192.168.24.130
[root@master ~]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.24.129: REDIRECT HOST (New next hob: 192.168.24.1)
from 192.168.24.129: Destination Host Prohibited
```

I have switched off all firewalls

```
service iptables stop
```

If I don't use the eth1 file, ie. delte it, I can ping to `8.8.8.8`. Can anyone help me so I can ping 8.8.8.8 as well with static IPs?

Comment: It looks like you've got your CentOS VM set as its own gateway. Maybe it doesn't know any routes off of the local subnet?

Comment: I editted my question, if I dont use static ips I can ping to 8.8.8.8, but I need to use static ip and can ping to 8.8.8.8

Comment: 192.168.24.1 is the IP of NAT for vmware but it say destination host is prohibited

Comment: Based on the output, it looks like Mat is right. Try switching it back to DHCP and verify the gateway IP and then switch back to static and match the static gateway IP with the DHCP gateway IP.

Comment: Er Spiff, not Mat.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch , Can you post a working example here, I just configured various parameters but still can't get ping 8.8.8.8 work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like the gateway isn't set properly so let's change `etho` back to DHCP to get the default gateway and make sure we can ping 8.8.8.8. I'm by no means a Linux expert, especially not CentOS as my preferred flavor is Ubuntu but after some reading, the instructions below should work to reset your Ethernet adapter back to DHCP and then grabbing the default gateway and finally resetting the Ethernet adapter back to your static IP address. And there are links at the end if you need more help.

In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, change:

> Bootproto=dhcp

Save the file and reboot the virtual machine or execute the command `service network restart` to restart your network. Once it restarts, try pinging 8.8.8.8

If the ping is successful, enter command `route -n` and find the row in the `Destination` column with  **0.0.0.0** and write down the address under the `Gateway` column in the same row.

Open `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and change `BootProTo' to none. Edit`IPADDR=`to whatever static address you want but make sure it is **not** the default gateway and make sure it's on the **same subnet**. If`IPADDR' doesn't show, add it. Once that's done, save the file, reboot the network or computer again and then try pinging 8.8.8.8.

I believe the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`are reset when you change `eth0` to DHCP so if the ping is successful, check `/etc/resolv.conf` and change the nameserver back to what you want, restart the network or virtual machine again and then try pinging 8.8.8.8 again.

Setting DHCP:
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html

Static configuration: http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-static-ip-address-in-centos/